# Software recommendations for magazine layout?

Tags: publishing, editing, software, pages

I use Word now but I would like to find a better software for laying out a magazine.

In this magazine, I would like to create columns (2 or 3 depending on the page), insert image on 1, 2 or 3 columns (like in a newspaper), independent frames on 1, 2 or 3 columns with text inside, a header and a footer different for the left or right page, etc.

Comment: You are searching this magazine, or formatting it for publishing?

Comment: Are you asking about software to use for making a magazine? Sorry, but your question isn't worded very well.

Comment: Sorry for my english. I am looking for software to use for making a magazine.

Comment: Word is not a desktop publishing program. Word is a word processing program. It is meant for long textual documents with minimal graphics.

Comment: Jonathan asked this same question on GraphicDesignSE, where one of the mods reworded it for coherence. I have copied his edits here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Adobe InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign.html) or [QuarkXPress](http://www.quark.com/). These are desktop publishing programs, which are designed to do exactly what you want to do (among many other things): lay out printed pieces like a magazine.

Comment: Thanks. I need this soft just for one document so I think I will use the QuarkXpress trial version.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for software to use for making a magazine, I would recommend [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus). It is open source desktop publishing software that is free. I haven't used it myself, but I know a couple of people who use it for a newsletter, and they really like it.

Answer (score 0):

And i would suggest Corel Draw. It helps really!

Comment: Can you please add details as to why you think is is useful?

Comment: Of course I can. But I won't be able to provide the full details as I am still learning. 
So, goto their website or youtube 'how to use corel'. You'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try X[iosis Scribe](http://www.xiosis.com). It has a free form layout which allows you to drag and re size paragraphs as you like. In addition to all the usual formatting features, it also keeps content separate from layout so your formatting won't affect the text.