# Free or cheap way to lay out a concert program booklet?

Tags: formatting, software, tools

I just volunteered to produce the concert program booklets for a recital series starting in October and I'm wondering what is the best way to go about creating a multi-page booklet that would include things like program notes, performer biographies, the evening's selections, some advertisements, contributor lists, and more odds and ends.

I suppose I could do battle with Microsoft Word, but when I used it some years back to produce a physics instructor's manual I suffered greatly.  Are there online tools I could learn to use that might do this job?  Is there a Google Drive tool that would work for this?

I have a habit of reinventing the wheel and working too hard instead of finding out the easy way to do things, so I'd appreciate any advice before I start.

---

*Added--*Thanks for the Scribus suggestion!  I downloaded it into my Mac and got it working rather quickly.  I started working through the tutorial and see that there are quite a few differences between versions that make it a little hard to know where to look for a box to check for this or that, but I think I can learn to use this to good effect if I put in the time ...

Comment: Related: [Software recommendations for magazine layout?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/3526/26)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case, fandom magazine, we decided to put the final layouting inside [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) which is open source and available for all operating systems.

For documents sharing, we use Facebook closed group, becase it offers:

- Document upload (for writing texts we use either Libre Office or MS Ofice)
- Discussion for every document version
- And of course, document version support
- And, *Everyone is on Facebook nowadays ;)*